httpx.ConnectError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy in snowflake Function call
I'm trying to invoke the google translate python code using snowflake python stored procedure. While invoking the function I'm getting error as
 File "/home/udf/83428393/httpcore.zip/httpcore/_exceptions.py", line 14, in map_exceptions
    raise to_exc(exc) from exc
httpcore.ConnectError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/f8ec62c410e9e3922c786641658c8c13d2fb99db0751b02297123925d6bd4997/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 84, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
httpx.ConnectError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy

I'm using httpx 0.26.1 version. Please suggest.

I believe you need to create an external access integration in Snowflake.
Please see all the details in the Snowflake docs.
Essentially:

Create a secret representing credentials

CREATE OR REPLACE SECRET oauth_token
TYPE = OAUTH2
API_AUTHENTICATION = google_translate_oauth
OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN = 'my-refresh-token';


Create a network rule representing the external network location

CREATE OR REPLACE NETWORK RULE google_apis_network_rule
MODE = EGRESS
TYPE = HOST_PORT
VALUE_LIST = ('translation.googleapis.com');


Create an external access integration using the secret and network rule

USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL ACCESS INTEGRATION google_apis_access_integration
ALLOWED_NETWORK_RULES = (google_apis_network_rule)
ALLOWED_AUTHENTICATION_SECRETS = (oauth_token)
ENABLED = true;


In your procedure definition, add EXTERNAL_ACCESS_INTEGRATIONS = (google_apis_access_integration) and SECRETS = ('cred' = oauth_token )

